# How can I repeat an object at specific locations?

Tags: modifiers

I want to build a bus, and repeat the passenger seat object. Array does not work, because the required locations are not regular. I need the seats at specific places.
How can i repeat the seat on several specific, defined locations?

Comment: thank you very much. is there somthing similar for Blender 2.79b?

Comment: I'm very rusty on older versions but you should look into *dupligroups* which is pretty much the same thing with the older hierarchy system

Comment: you can use Instancing > Vertices or Faces on a subdivided edge or face loop, or even Particlesystem > Hair on vertices

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***Instancing***: Create a plane made of a series of faces, rearrange them the way you want (as you don't want a straight line), in the *Properties panel > Object > Instancing*, enable *Faces*, then parent your chair object to the plane:

[image]

If you want to make each object independent, select and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Make Instances Real*.

A pretty close solution would be to use *ParticleSystem > Hair* with your object as hair.

Comment: Thank you very much. ill do instancing on vertex, as instancing on face implements rotation for some reason. 
Instancing on Empty Objects would be better to handle though.

Comment: yes Gorgious' solution is good too. Instancing on vertices won't take orientation into account, Instancing on faces will